# What is name of Flag 402653184 and what is use of it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I search on Internet but didn't find answer.

I found that many Launcher app is using flag **402653184** see below code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.setFlags(402653184);
try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) { 

}
```

I check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent but didn't fina any name for constant value **402653184**

> What is use of 402653184?
>
> What is Name of Constant value for 402653184?

Comment: Where did you find this code? because it is not available in [**`setFlags()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

Comment: Try printing the value as hexadecimal and see what bits in it are set. Compare to the bits in the documentation.

Comment: I found that source code from 2 launcher application. And I am also stuck at some issue in my launcher app.

Comment: 402653184 = 0x18000000 = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

Comment: Combined value of both the flag?

Comment: it is not a single flag, it isa mask.